# parameterizing intersections of 2 planes

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The curve C is the intersection of $x^2+y^2=1$ and $2x+y+z=4$

Finding the curve C according to the book is doing cylinder coordination such that, $x=cos\theta , y=sin\theta,z=4-sin(\theta)-2(cos(\theta)), 0 \leq \theta \ \leq2\pi$

but i don't they chose that approach to describe the intersections between the 2 planes

Answer (score 0):

$x^2+y^2=1$ is a cylinder and $2x+y+z=4$ is a plane

The intersection is an ellipse (in blue in the picture below) whose parametric equations are

$$(x=\cos \theta,y=\sin \theta,z=4-\sin  \theta-2 \cos \theta);\;\theta\in[0,2\pi]\tag{1}$$

Because $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$ so the curve $(1)$ satisfies the equation of the cylinder. Furthermore $z=4-y-2x$ is the explicit equation of the plane, so $(1)$ satisfies the equation of the plane, too.

---

$$...$$
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the plane

$$\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^\color{red}{2}\;:\; x^2+y^2=1\}$$

is a circle with $(0,0)$ as center and $ R=1 $ as radius.

In the space
$$\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^\color{red}{3}\;:\; x^2+y^2=1\}$$
is a vertical cylinder which can be parametrized as

$$x=\cos(t)$$
$$y=\sin(t)$$
$$z=z$$

If a point $ (x,y,z) $ lies in the intersection, then
$$x=\cos(t)$$
$$y=\sin(t)$$
$$z=4-2x-y=4-2\cos(t)-\sin(t)$$
where $ t\in [0,2\pi]$.